# How to pass the localStorage values to a usestate variable and updating with useEffects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

My project ideea: i want to randomly generate a noun from a js file and when I press a button, that noun to be saved in localStorage(i save all the array, just change that noun property from isFavorite=false to isFavorite=true). In another page, i want to display all the saved nouns.
I have 2 pages: **NewNouns** and **FavoriteWords**.
In the **NewNouns** page I added an array of Objects (this array contains more nouns with some properties). Also, in this page i updated the objects array when I press a button to change the isFavorite value from false to true.

In the **FavoriteWords** page I have a usestate that receives the values from the localStorage. I displayed on the screen all the nouns with the isFavorite property=true. I want to add to these nouns the possibility to be deleted when I press a button.

**My problem is:** I don't know why my usestate from FavoriteWords page doesn't receive the values from the localStorage (**this problem appears just when I use the useEffects to update the deleted nouns**). If I don't use useEffect, everything works ok. But I need useEffect because my components have to re-render when I'm deleting a noun.

----Example of Object Array ----

```
export default [{"id":0,"value":"Diamond","translation":"Diamant","isFavorite":false,"appeard":false},
                 {"id":1,"value":" Manager","translation":" Manager","isFavorite":false,"appeard":false},
                 {"id":2,"value":" Area","translation":" Zona","isFavorite":false,"appeard":false}
                ]
```

----NewNouns Page----

```
import arrayNounsData from '../../Datas/nouns'

const NewNouns = () => {
  const[word,setWord]=React.useState(arrayNounsData.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())[0])//the noun displayed
  const[words,setWords]=React.useState(()=>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("nouns")) || arrayNounsData) //the Objects array
 
  
  function addToFavorite(){ 
    setWords(prevValue=>prevValue.map(wordData =>{
      return wordData.id === word.id ?
      {
        ...wordData,
        isFavorite: !wordData.isFavorite
      }
      : {...wordData  }})) 
  }
 
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem("nouns", JSON.stringify(words))
  },[words])
  
  return ( 
    <>
        {....}
    </>
  )
}
```

----FavoriteWords Page----

```
const FavoriteWords = () => {
    const [words,setWords]=React.useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(nouns)) || []) //all the array from NewNouns page
    const [favoriteWords, setFavoriteWords]=React.useState(words.filter(word => word.isFavorite === true))//extract just the savedNouns

    const word=favoriteWords.map(word =>(
      <Word
        key={word.id}
        id={word.id}
        word={word.value}
        deleteFromFavorite={deleteFromFavorite}
      />
    ) )

    function deleteFromFavorite(wordId){ 
      setFavoriteWords(prevValue=>prevValue.map(wordData =>{
        return wordData.id === wordId ?
        {
          ...wordData,
          isFavorite:false
        }
        : {...wordData  }}))
      setDeleteWords(prevValue=>prevValue.map(wordData =>{
        return wordData.id === wordId ?
        {
          ...wordData,
          isFavorite: false
        }
        : {...wordData  }}))
    }
   /* React.useEffect(()=>{
      localStorage.setItem("notes" , JSON.stringify(words))
    }, [words])
   */

  return (
    <WordsContainer >
          {word}
    </WordsContainer>
  )
}
export default FavoriteWords

const Word = (props) => {
  return (
      <SelectedContainer >
          {props.word}
          <TrashIcon src={Trash} onClick={() => props.deleteFromFavorite(props.id)} />
      </SelectedContainer> 
  )
}
```

I used the useEffect hook to re render the components to update the displayed nouns. The problem is that **when I use it**, the 'words' useState (from FavoriteWords page) it's initialized with [], and not with localStorage values. I don't know why. **How the useEffect works in this case?**

Comment: `localStorage.getItem(nouns)` missing quotes?

Comment: `setDeleteWords` does not exist in your pasted code, yet it is referenced. Did you post the whole thing as is in its broken state?

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` method is mostly for joining technologies that don't fit into the React lifecycle. While `localStorage` generally fits that model, there is no observability on the `localStorage` value between renders. React rendering lifecycle isn't aware of calls to `localStorage.setItem`. This is an example interface for `localStorage` as `useState` wrappers. Feel free to mess with the abstraction and make it yours:

```
function useLocalStorageArray(key, defaultValue = []) {
  const [value, setter] = useState(() => {
    let current = localStorage.getItem(key)
    if (!current) {
      current = JSON.stringify(defaultValue)
      localStorage.setItem(key, current)
    }
    return JSON.parse(current);
  })
  const setValue = useCallback((value) => {
    setter(() => {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
      return value;
    })
  }, [setter])
  return [value, setValue]
}
```

This is doing 3 things:

1. Setting the default `localStorage` value to sync state upon render.
2. Setting the React state for what we care about.
3. Setting the `localStorage` to new values when using `setValue`.

Now you can just use your abstraction like you would `useState`. Each call to `setWords` will trigger the render lifecycle as well as update your `localStorage` `key`.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [words, setWords] = useLocalStorageArray("nouns", arrayNounsData) // Using the thing
  // ...
}
```